# Arithmetic on DB Table's Vertical Data

Tags: sql, postgresql

If I have a table with few `columns` like the following, then arithmetic is easy, wherein the formula for result is stored elsewhere.

```
Table Result
```

| id | name | columnA | columnB | columnC | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | 10 | 2 | 4 | A*B/C=20 |

In case the Values of ColumnA, ColumnB, and ColumnC are stored in Master Table and The Data Values in another Table as follows, then what should be the approach

```
Table Master
```

| id | related_to | column_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test1 | columnA |
| 2 | test1 | columnB |
| 3 | test1 | columnC |
| 4 | test2 | columnA |
| 5 | test2 | columnB |

```
Table Formula
```

| id | related_to | Formula |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test1 | columnA * columnB / columnC |
| 2 | test2 | (columnA + columnB ) / 2 |

```
Table Data_Source
```

| id | related_to | column_id | column_name | column_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test1 | 1 | columnA | 10 |
| 2 | test1 | 2 | columnB | 2 |
| 3 | test1 | 3 | columnC | 4 |
| 4 | test2 | 1 | columnA | 8 |
| 5 | test2 | 2 | columnB | 8 |

Please advise on possible SQL statements for populating the Table Result

Comment: Your formulas must be executed within a query using some sort of SQL injection. You really have to know what you're doing, to keep something like this safe. Advise: Don't do it, fix this issue in your application layer instead of the database layer.

Comment: I was thinking to Use `trigger` as it appears to be safer and easier option

Comment: With or without a trigger, you still need SQL injection to get this one working. Any "formula" like "DROP TABLE ..." would be executed. That's most likely the reason you get a downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this. It is limited to one JOIN per column (so not an arbitrary number of columns where a crosstab would be the way to go) and there may be better methods, but this answers your question I think. Basically it reconstitutes your original table. I haven't tested it for typos, etc.

```
SELECT related_to name, formula.formula result, cola.column_value columnA, colb.column_value columnB, colc.column_value columnC
FROM master 
    JOIN formula ON master.related_to = formula.related_to
    JOIN data_source cola ON 'columnA' = data_source.column_name
            AND master.related_to = data_source.related_to
    JOIN data_source colb ON 'columnB' = data_source.column_name
            AND master.related_to = data_source.related_to
    JOIN data_source colb ON 'columnC' = data_source.column_name
            AND master.related_to = data_source.related_to
```